# How to create, edit, and save file through MS Shell from Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, save, dos, metasploit, windows-xp-sp2

I'm working on exploiting a bug on Windows XP SP2 by using Metasploit and I do this from Ubuntu terminal.

Now, I have connected to Windows Shell but now I have small problem with saving my text file. I am using `edit file.txt` command and then type the content of file. The problem is when I press `CTRL+Z` it closes my `msfconsole` without saving the file.

What are other ways to save that file without GUI?

Comment: Can you not bypass EDIT entirely, and simply type the content of the file, redirecting output to file.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @dbenham suggested, you can do something like:

```
> echo First line of file > file.txt
> echo Second line of file >> file.txt
...
> echo Last line of file >> file.txt
```

***Note**:* `...` *is not a command, it's just to represent the lines that would be in between.*